# Get resource from RegEx String

Tags: java, regex, resources, expression

After hours of searching and trying and failing, I decided to ask my question here. I want to replace `:(.+?):` in a string with the resource loaded from /src. For example if I would type in ":foo.bar:" it would replace it with `this.getClass().getResource("foo.bar");`.

My concrete situation:
I have a little chat application using smileys, located in the "smileys"-folder in "src". If a user types ":foo:", it should get the full URL of "smileys/foo.png", if the file exists (`this.getClass().getResource("smileys/foo.png");` in this case) and put it into  tags. So for example if a user types "foo :bar:", it should be converted into "foo C:/<...>/smileys/bar.png".

How could I do this?
Thank you for your answers,

Benni

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below code will do what you want:

```
String s = "x = :foo.bar: ;";
String res = s.replaceAll(":(.+?):","this.getClass().getResource(\"$1\")");
System.out.println(res);
```

prints

```
x = this.getClass().getResource("foo.bar") ;
```

Comment: Yeah, but what if I want it to execute `this.getClass().getResource("foo.bar")`? How can I do that?

Comment: Java code has to be compiled before execution, so you can not do that. It is possible in some interpreted languages i.e JavaScript but not in Java.

Comment: I know it has to be compiled. But I'm sure it has to work. My situation: I have got a chat, which uses emoticons. They are located in the "smileys"-folder, If a user types ":foo:", it should get the full URL of "smileys/foo.png", if the file exists (`this.getClass().getResource("smileys/foo.png");` in this case) and put it into <img> tags. So for example if a user types "foo :bar:", it should be converted into "foo C:/<...>/smileys/bar.png".

Comment: Yes, I do. There is HTMLEditorKit, which I can use to style my content with HTML.

Comment: I am not familiar with **HTMLEditorKit**  but if it was JSP I will write a tag to pull the right image, something like `<mytag:getImage name="foo.bar"/>`

Answer (score 0):

They explain how to do this in the documentation  provided by oracle.This normally to all regex in all languages though, not just java.

" A backreference is specified in the regular expression as a backslash () followed by a digit indicating the number of the group to be recalled. For example, the expression (\d\d) defines one capturing group matching two digits in a row, which can be recalled later in the expression via the backreference \1.

To match any 2 digits, followed by the exact same two digits, you would use (\d\d)\1 as the regular expression:

```
Enter your regex: (\d\d)\1

Enter input string to search: 1212

I found the text "1212" starting at index 0 and ending at index 4.
```

If you change the last two digits the match will fail:

```
Enter your regex: (\d\d)\1

Enter input string to search: 1234
No match found.
```

For nested capturing groups, backreferencing works in exactly the same way: Specify a backslash followed by the number of the group to be recalled."

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html

Comment: Yes. Until this step I could did it. But what if I my expression is ":(.+?):" for example, and I want to have it converted into `this.getClass().getResource("$1")`. For example:
`String reg = ":foo: asdf :bar:";
reg = reg.replaceAll(":(.+?):", this.getClass().getResource("$1"));`
But this doesn't work, because I can't set the parameter `$1` as a argument of a function.

Comment: @Benni I don't believe you can do that all in one line. One way comes to mind: You have to use that regex expression and split the string(there is a split function), and put it into an array. Then pass each value of the array to the function and store it at the first occurrence of the expression one at a time.